# How to check which packages a certain `brew` package is used in?

Tags: homebrew

I would expect an API like

```
brew enables --installed
```

It seems this information is available, otherwise how does `brew autoremove` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`brew uses` might be what you are looking for.

E.g. `brew uses --installed openssl@1.1` will list all installed packages that use openssl@1.1

`brew uses --eval-all openssl@1.1` will list all packages that use openssl@1.1

See the documentation:

> Show formulae and casks that specify formula as a dependency; that is, show dependents of formula. When given multiple formula arguments, show the intersection of formulae that use formula. By default, uses shows all formulae and casks that specify formula as a required or recommended dependency for their stable builds.